# Why my code insert only one to DB when i use foreach

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I need to insert data to database by use foreach
But my code only insert last one, Please help me to find out why?

**Post Data**

```
{
"APIPassword": "Test",
"Method": "Transfer",
"Data": [
    {
        "Account": "Test01",
        "Amount": 100,
        "TransactionNo": "Test1",
        "dbID": "Bet1"
    },
    {
        "Account": "Test02",
        "Amount": -100,
        "TransactionNo": "Test2",
        "dbID": "Bet2"
    }
]}
```

**My Code**

```
$apiPassword = $data['APIPassword'];
$method = $data['Method'];
$datas = $data['Data'];

$db = new db();

foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $db->userId = '1';
    $db->account = $data['Account'];
    $db->amount = (float) $data['Amount'];
    $db->transactionNo = $data['TransactionNo'];
    $db->dbID = $data['dbID'];
    $db->save();
}
```

**Result when submit**

```
"Account": "Test02",
    "Amount": -100,
    "TransactionNo": "Test2",
    "db": "Bet2"
```

Comment: You are setting the userId = 1 in all cases, so it overwrites

Comment: @MarkoPaju What problem in userId because userId can be same data.

Comment: @MarkoPaju I have column "id" as primary key. "userId" is user profile id.

Comment: add `break;` after `$db->save()` and see if it inserts the first one

Comment: @MarkoPaju Yeah, it insert first one but i need to insert it all.

Comment: Right, so if it inserts the first one, then it is overwritten!

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a new db object each time in the for loop, in your current code you are using the same object on each iteration of the loop.

Change your code to this:

```
$apiPassword = $data['APIPassword'];
$method = $data['Method'];
$datas = $data['Data'];

foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $db = new db();
    $db->userId = '1';
    $db->account = $data['Account'];
    $db->amount = (float) $data['Amount'];
    $db->transactionNo = $data['TransactionNo'];
    $db->dbID = $data['dbID'];
    $db->save();
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem because the save function is context sensitive. Previously, instantiating db outside the loop created one object and save would create the object in the database on the first iteration and update the object on subsequent iterations. Instantiating inside the loop will make save perform a create operation each time because a new db object will be created each time

Comment: Please add such context directly to your next answer, that makes it even more valuable than a simple „use this code“

Answer (score 0):

What is `$db = new db();`, does `db` corresponds to a model? Try like this:

```
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $db = new db(); // <-- Important part
    $db->userId = '1';
    $db->account = $data['Account'];
    $db->amount = (float) $data['Amount'];
    $db->transactionNo = $data['TransactionNo'];
    $db->dbID = $data['dbID'];
    $db->save();
}
```

Perhaps in a later stage of your app you may want to update records. If `dbID` is your unique record key, you will do something like:

```
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $item = db::findFirst([
        'conditions' => 'dbID = :dbID:',
        'bind' => [
            'dbID' => $data['dbID']
        ]
    ]);

    // Record does not exist in our DB - skip or even create it?
    if ($item === false) {
        continue;
    }

    // Proceed with updating data
    $item->account = $data['Account'];
    $item->amount = (float) $data['Amount'];
    $item->transactionNo = $data['TransactionNo'];
    $item->save();
}
```